# Investigate the convergence of the integral

Tags: real-analysis

Investigate the convergence of the integral 
$$\int_{0}^{1} \left\vert \sin\frac{1}{x} \right\vert\ \frac{1}{x^{\alpha}} dx \ \text{where $\alpha \geq 1$  }$$

I assume that it diverges, so I rated function from below
$|sin\frac{1}{x}| \ \frac{1}{x^{\alpha }} \geq \sin^2(\frac{1}{x}) \ \frac{1}{x^\alpha} = \frac {(1-cos(\frac{2}{x}))}{2x^\alpha } = \frac{1}{2x^\alpha} - \frac {cos(\frac{2}{x})}{x^\alpha}$

The $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{2x^{\alpha}} dx$ diverges

How to show that the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac {cos(\frac{2}{x})}{x^\alpha}$ converges?

Comment: I am not sure this is the way to go since you are left with something as difficult to prove as the first assertion.

Comment: I got rid of the module

Comment: Sorr y,I sealed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using integration by substitution, we have to study the convergence of the integral

$$I_\alpha=\int_1^\infty x^{\alpha-2}  \left\vert \sin x \right\vert \ dx.$$

For $k \in \mathbb N$, and $x \in [k \pi + \frac{\pi}{6}, k\pi + \frac{5\pi}{6}]$, you have

$$\left\vert \sin x \right\vert \ge \frac{1}{2}$$ hence

$$g(x) = x^{\alpha-2}\left\vert \sin x \right\vert   \ge \frac{x^{\alpha-2}}{2}.$$

Based on that, you get

$$I_\alpha \ge \frac{\pi}{3} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\left(k\pi + \frac{5\pi}{6}\right)^{2-\alpha}}.$$

As the right end series is diverging for $2- \alpha \le 1$, i.e. $\alpha \ge 1$, we finally get that the integral is also diverging for $\alpha \ge 1$.

Comment: Is it possible to do the task as I tried?

Comment: I don't see how as you still have a trigonometric map of $1/x$ which is the annoying thing.

Comment: @ShVavilenT Looking it twice, I think that you can succeed based using the trigonometric identity $\sin^2 x = 1- \cos 2x$. For this, use the integration by substitution that I made at the start of my answer to get rid of $\sin (1/x)$. Then use what you did plus an integration by part.

Comment: ok, i see,thanks

Comment: I correctly understood ,that you broke the integral into the sum of the integrals, each integral is defined and you computed them?

Comment: That is almost correct. I even didn't compute the integral but used monotonicity of $x \to 1/x^\beta$.

Comment: initial integral  = $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\int_{+6}^{+56}function $?

Comment: $\int_1^\infty f = \sum_k \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} f \ge \sum_k \int_{\pi+\pi/6}^{\pi+5\pi/6} f \ge 3\pi/3\sum_k f(\pi+5\pi/6)$ if $f$ is supposed to be non negative decreasing.

Comment: Thank you so mach )))